# How to set thickness of circular indeterminate progress bar android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml, android-progressbar

I have two nested circular indeterminate progress bars but I cannot set their thickness to an equal size. I have tried to customize it using shapes.  However, that removes the default behaviour of the circular indeterminate progress.
I customize like this and it made thickness equal but not getting default behaviour.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate android:toDegrees="360">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thickness="4dp">
                <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>

<ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/download_progress4"
      android:layout_width="85dp"
      android:layout_height="85dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:indeterminate="true"
      android:indeterminateDrawable="@style/ProgressThem" />
```

I want like this with default behaviour of circular indeterminate progress bar

[image: but i want like this with default behaviour of circular indeterminate progress bar]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

USE

```
android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
android:thicknessRatio="20.0
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate android:toDegrees="360">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thickness="4dp"
                android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
                android:thicknessRatio="20.0">
                <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: How to use it, set as drawable inside ProgressBar?

Answer (score 9):

If you want the modern animation rather than just rotation, you can copy and alter https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_anim_medium_material.xml using it as the `indeterminateDrawable`.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/new_progress_indeterminate_anim_medium_material"
```

To change the width in vector_drawable_progress_bar_medium.xml `android:strokeWidth="1"` for example.

It's a bit painful to do this as you also need to copy over the animation, interpolator and animator xml files to your project as they are private in the Android SDK.

Comment: among tens of other answers this one is perfect because it is not changing the behaviour of indeterminate progress bar!

Answer (score 9):

There is actually an even easier way to do that with the material components:

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        app:trackThickness="3dp" />
```

More details in material docs -> https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/android#circular-progress-indicators