# Circular progress bar thickness that's thicker the head and thinner on the tail

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-progressbar

How can I create progress bar with that kind of thickness, that is thicker on the head and thinner on the tail? Also I want it to be indeterminate

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try this git library it will help you and give more customization  https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar...

```
mProgressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(new SmoothProgressDrawable.Builder(context)
.strokeWidth(8f)            //You should use Resources#getDimension
.build());
```

You can give any stroke width here.

Comment: or you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48581834/how-to-set-thickness-of-circular-indeterminate-progress-bar-android

Comment: thank you for the answer, but it's not exactly what I want